# Is there an option for automatic recursion for a massive amount of subdirs?

Tags: recursion, makefile, autotools, automake

I'm wanting to set up a system to automatically create Makefiles for a class. I have each chapter broken up into examples, labs, and homework and each subsequent directory there are Makefiles as well.

I want to know what I can do (asides from adding SUBDIRS for each parent node) to automate this process.

As it stands, the parent of CH01, has a Makefile.am that has SUBDIRS and the `homework` directory does the same as well.

Part of configure.ac:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([CH01/Makefile
                 CH01/examples/Makefile
                 CH01/homework/Makefile
                 CH01/homework/HW2/Makefile
                 CH02/Makefile
                 CH02/examples/Makefile
                 CH02/homework/Makefile
                 CH02/labs/Makefile
                 CH03/Makefile
                 CH03/examples/Makefile
                 CH03/homework/Makefile
                 CH03/labs/Makefile
                 CH04/Makefile
                 CH04/examples/Makefile
                 CH04/homework/Makefile
                 CH04/labs/Makefile
                 Makefile])
```

Directory Listing:

```
├── CH01
│   ├── examples
│   │   ├── hello
│   │   ├── hello.cpp
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── Makefile.am
│   │   └── Makefile.in
│   ├── homework
│   │   ├── HW1
│   │   │   ├── README.pdf
│   │   │   └── README.tex
│   │   ├── HW2
│   │   │   ├── hw2.cpp
│   │   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   │   ├── Makefile.am
│   │   │   ├── Makefile.in
│   │   │   ├── README.pdf
│   │   │   └── README.tex
│   │   ├── HW3
│   │   │   ├── README.pdf
│   │   │   └── README.tex
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── Makefile.am
│   │   └── Makefile.in
│   ├── labs
│   │   ├── README.pdf
│   │   └── README.tex
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── Makefile.am
│   └── Makefile.in
```

Full directory listing: http://pastebin.com/Ju5MwXxt

Comment: And what is in these makefiles? What do they do?

Comment: If it is in a homework directory, then it will compile a corresponding program. For example, HW2's Makefile will compile a program called hw2 (from hw2.cpp). CH01's Makefile should go and create all the make files for the subdirectories. So CH01's Makefile will create the Makefile for homework which will make the makefile for HW2.

Comment: That doesn't sound too difficult. It will be easier if e.g. `HW1/Makefile` and `HW2/Makefile` are identical, and easier still if you are comfortable with the use of symbolic links. Will you show us `HW2/Makefile`, or should we guess about what it contains?

Comment: Here is the Makefile.am:  http://pastebin.com/qe4RCKpB I can dump all of the Makefile, but it will look just like a cookie cutter automake to make file.

Comment: I can't help with automake, but conceptually this is not a difficult problem.